# How do I upgrade the PHP MySQL Library?

Tags: php, mysql, centos

My PHP MySQL Library version is out of date with my MySQL Vesion. How do I fix this?

Server: CentOS 6.3

Steps Taken:

- FRESH machine originally installed with MySQL 5.1 and PHP 5.3
- I uninstalled php and then installed php54w (and most dependancies, including php54w-mysql from webtatic)
- I uninstalled mysql and installed mysql55 mysql55-server from webtatic

At this point everything is fine but my mysql lib is out of sync (message form phpmyadmin): "Your PHP MySQL library version 5.1.69 differs from your MySQL server version 5.5.31. This may cause unpredictable behavior."

Now, I know some people have suggested that this is fine for the most bit, but this will be a production machine and I don't want to assume it will be fine.

- I tried removing and re-installing php54w-mysql, didn't work

So, how do I upgrade the PHP MySQL Library?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps to take should have been:

1). Clear the cache in `yum`:

`yum clean all` 
 2). Update your system:

`yum --obsoletes update` 
 3). Add the `remi` repository to your server:

> rpm -Uvh
>   http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm 
>   rpm -Uvh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm

4). Upgrade PHP (without uninstalling it first):

> yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-test update httpd mysql mysql-server php
>   php-common

Comment: are these steps i can still take?

Comment: I would recommend starting with a fresh install as there might be broken dependencies.

Comment: There is no way to simply upgrade the one library? Everything else is working perfect... a fresh install seems like overkill.

Comment: You can try downgrading to PHP 5.3.x and then running the update. If that doesn't work, then you can repeat by also downgrading MySQL. Since you started with a fresh install though, it's always easiest to work from that, rather than trying to fix broken installs.

Comment: I followed your steps and it installed php 5.5.3, not 5.4 - how to select a specific version?

Comment: Do you want a specific version of PHP, or just the latest?

Comment: n/m, removed remi-test from repo list

Comment: OK, hope it works out for you! :-)

Comment: It has... got everything up and running properly... I completely removed the php54w and mysql55 installs from webtatic and started over with remi

Comment: Great - glad it helped! Thanks for the updates so others will know too.